# Past participle equivalent of "absurd"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a past participle equivalent of *absurd*? More specifically, is there a verb meaning *to make absurd* that has a past participle form (*made absurd*)?

This is similar to how the word *inverted* operates in the phrase *the inverted world*: covering not just the description of the world as currently being inverted, but also the implication that in the past the world was not inverted, but was made to be at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first question is:

> Is there a past participle equivalent of the word absurd?

No, because *absurd* itself is not a verb, but an adjective. Adjectives don't have past participles.

Your second question, which was more specific:

> Or more specifically is there a verb meaning "to make absurd" that has a past participle form ("made absurd")?

Yes, there is a verb meaning "to make absurd"; it's [stultify](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stultify)(guess how long it took me to find that!):

> to render absurdly...[To cause to appear foolish.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stultify)

The past participle of this would be "stultified"

That should answer your question.

Comment: I was puzzled by your choice of the word 'stultify' as I was only familiar with sense (1) [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stultify).  But there it has also sense (2), well found!

Comment: @z7sg, that's why I wrote that little parentheses after the word "stultify"!

Answer (score 0):

'Inverted' in your example, with either meaning, is performing an adjectival role, not a verbal role. 
As for the verb you're looking for, "to make absurd" could be closely be replaced with 'trivialise' in which case the past participle would be 'got trivialised.'

So it could be used as in "He trivialised the issue far too much."
or
"The trivialised matters are actually the ones worth re-investigating."

Comment: Trivialise means 'make less important', not 'make absurd'.